# Search for and replace characters in a string in assembly nasm issues

Tags: string, assembly, replace, 64-bit, nasm

I've got this working to where it copies a string into another. I'm trying to make it search for a term and swap it. For some reason, if the replace function isn't commented, it somehow manages to delete the output in the console (literally goes backwards!). If I comment the replace function out, I just get an exact copy. Trying to change cat to dog.

```
    bits 64
    global main
    extern printf

    section .text
main:
    ; function setup
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32
    ;
    lea     rdi, [rel message]
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf

    ;print source message
    lea     rdi, [rel source]
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf

    ;print target message
    lea     rdi, [rel target]
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf



    lea rdi, [rel target]
    lea rsi, [rel source]
    cld
    jmp Loop

Loop:
    lodsb       ;Load byte at address RSI into AL
    stosb       ;Store AL at address RDI
    ;push   [rdi]   
    cmp byte RDI, 'c'
    je  replace     
    ;pop [rdi]
    test al,al  ;code will jump only if al is not equ 0
    jnz Loop

replace:
    ;lea     rdi, [rel success]
    mov byte [rdi], 'd'
    ;call    printf 
     ret





;print new version of target
    lea     rdi, [rel target]
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf



; function return
mov     eax, 0
add     rsp, 32
pop     rbp
ret

section .data
message: db      'Project:',0x0D,0x0a,'Author:',0x0D,0x0a,0x0D,0x0a,0

source:  db "The cat chased the bird.",0x0a,0x0D,0
target:  db '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',0x0D,0x0a,0

success: db "Success",0
```

Comment: Is the `ret` after the `replace` label intentional?

Comment: I put it there to return to the calling function, but i guess the stack takes care of that.

Comment: @user3866044: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want. I tested it in Ubuntu 64 with:
(assumed this file is a.asm)

`nasm -f elf64 -l a.lst  a.asm`  &
`gcc -m64 -o a a.o`

```
bits 64
global main
extern printf

section .text
main:
; function setup
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
sub     rsp, 32
;
lea     rdi, [rel message]
mov     al, 0
call    printf

;print source message
lea     rdi, [rel source]
mov     al, 0
call    printf

;print target message
lea     rdi, [rel target]
mov     al, 0
call    printf

lea rdi, [rel target]
lea rsi, [rel source]
cld

Loop:

lodsb       ;Load byte at address RSI into AL
stosb       ;Store AL at address RDI

cmp  al, 'c'
jne  LoopBack

lodsb       ;Load byte at address RSI into AL
stosb       ;Store AL at address RDI
cmp  al, 'a'
jne  LoopBack

lodsb       ;Load byte at address RSI into AL
stosb       ;Store AL at address RDI
cmp  al, 't'
jne  LoopBack

sub rdi, 3
mov byte [rdi], 'd'
inc rdi
mov byte [rdi], 'o'
inc rdi
mov byte [rdi], 'g'
inc rdi

LoopBack:
cmp al, 0
jne Loop

;print new version of target
lea     rdi, [rel target]
mov     al, 0
call    printf

; function return
mov     eax, 0
add     rsp, 32
pop     rbp
ret

section .data
message: db      'Project:',0x0D,0x0a,'Author:',0x0D,0x0a,0x0D,0x0a,0

source:  db "The cat chased the bird.",0x0a,0x0D,0
target:  db '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',0x0D,0x0a,0

success: db "Success",0
```

The output is this:

```
Project:
Author:

The cat chased the bird.
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
The dog chased the bird.
```

Comment: You are doing the same test twice. "cmp al,0;jne Loop" "test al,al;jnz Loop"

Comment: You are right. I forgot to remove it, however it has no effect. It was remained from questioner's question.

Comment: If you use `rdi`, don't increment, decrement `di` only.